# Where / how would you store the fact that someone has previously used an application or agreed to something like Terms of Service?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm in the process of building an application, which will show a 'Getting started' or 'How to use' guide/view when they first load the application. I was wondering whether there's such a thing as 'application preferences' that I could store whether or not a user has seen and "ok'd" this initial page or if it's something I'll need to use CoreData for? The same would go for the applications Terms of Service, whether I store the fact they've agreed in some sort of app preferences or CoreData.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `NSUserDefaults` is good enough. If you have a server, you can also store it on your server linking to the user's account so one login back will not see it again.

Comment: that gets wiped when you deinstall the app BUT for the mentioned points I'd say it's good

Comment: Yeah, that's the sort of thing I was looking for. Perfect! If they remove the app and re-install it, I'm happy for them to go through it again so that's not a problem. Thanks